# How can i compare two columns to see if the value in the B cell appears anywhere in column A?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 columns like this (yep, Porn)

```
A                           B
menshealthbase.com          XVIDEOS.COM
dailyrx.com                 ASHLEYRNADISON.COM
puzzleovergames.com         PORNHUB.COM
adventuregamesland.com      DOUBLEPIMP.COM
```

and i'd like to see if the value in cell B1 appears anywhere in column A (the actual column is over 20,000 values). If yes, then I'd like it to print either a 'yes' or 'no' in column C

Any suggestions? my experience with vlookup is limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in column C:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1, A:A, 0)), "Found", "")
```

This will search column A for the value in `B1` and return "Found" if it's found or leave it blank otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Uppercase Column A

[image: Step 1 Uppercase Column A]

Step 2 MATCH them

[image: Step 2 Match them]