# Highlight Cell in Column B if Value from Column A is Found Anywhere in Column B

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns, CODE_1 and CODE_2.  CODE_1 is a list of individual values and CODE_2 is a list of strings where a cell may contain more than 1 value from CODE_1.

I want to highlight cells in CODE_2 if a value from CODE_1 was found in that string.

Here are the 2 columns:

```
CODE_1          CODE_2
HSACAF          ERHCV
EBENTX          GTL
GTL             GTL
HSARNT          ERDEN, ERHCV, ERVSN
ERMS            ERDEN, ERHCV, ERVSN
MVNTX           ERDEN, ERHCV, ERVSN
334             ERDEN, ERHCV, ERVSN
SOE             ERDEN, ERHCV, ERVSN
CASHTIP         ERDEN, ERHCV, ERVSN
CREDTIPN        ART
CREDTIPP        GTL
INDIRTIPN       GOA
INDIRTIPP       ERHCV
ERDEN           ERHCV
ERHCV           DED
ERVSN           ERHCV
NVMBT           ERHCV
```

Based on these values, all cells in CODE_2 would be highlighted except the ones containing "ART", "GOA" and "DED".

This post came close ([How can i compare two columns to see if the value in the B cell appears anywhere in column A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272900/how-can-i-compare-two-columns-to-see-if-the-value-in-the-b-cell-appears-anywhere)), but didn't work to find if the value in CODE_2 was in a STRING, rather only if the searched value was the only value in the cell.  :-(

For example, it highlighted only CODE_2 rows "ERHCV"and "GTL".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess persistence counts for something!

The formula from that other post worked...

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B:B, 0)), "Found", "")
```

A and B are switched in the formula because I reversed the column order as well.

I'll give that post a vote.

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time on this!

Thanks!